# Is there any way to declare T in constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I'm having problem while using constructor because of lacking of my Kotlin knowledge. I searched and searched, but what I could get was only using generics in methods or classes

I'm using both java classes and Kotlin classes. I will give you an example

```
class A<T extends Enum<T> & A.Type<T>> {
    interface Type<T extends Enum<T> & Type<T>> {
        String getData();
    }

    public enum Example implements Type<Example> {
        HELLO("data1"),
        WORLD("data2");

        public Example(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        private final String data;

        @Override
        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public enum Example2 implements Type<Example2> {
        BYE("1Data"),
        WORLD("2Data");

        public Example2(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        private final String data;

        @Override
        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    //And there are several enum classes

    public final T[] types;

    public A(T[] type) {
        types = type;
    }

    public String get(T t) {
        for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            if(types[i] == t) {
                return types[i].getData();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Don't know proper usage of this class because I made it while I'm writing this question, but basic structure is like this. What I'm really using is more complicated thing (not made by me), so explaining problem I'm having will be better with this class. So I will be able to initialize class A by calling thing like `new A(A.Example.values());`

Now let's assume that I want to use this `A` as parameter in constructor in Class called `B`

```
class B {
    var data: String = ""

    val a: A<*>

    constructor(a: A<*>) {
        this.a = a
        this.data = a.get(a.types[0]) //This is the problem
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to set `data` by calling `a.get(a.types[0])` for default data, Kotlin causes problem because `a.get()` requires `Nothing` while `a.types[0]` is `Enum<*>`

I think I may be able to fix this by specifying `*` as something, but I can't figure out correct generics... Declaring T to specify that T extends Enum, and implements Type will be the way I'm thinking. Method can be done similar like this way, but I couldn't in constuctor. Putting `Any` instead of `*` also didn't work because it says `Any` doesn't extend `Enum`

Can this problem be solved or do I have to find alternative way without using generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to do both `get` and `types` in one operation, so the compiler knows the types match. I think an extension method should work as well as a method declared inside `A`:

```
fun <T> A<T>.getByIndex(i: Int) where T: A.Type<T>, T: Enum<T> = get(types[i])

// in B's constructor
this.data = a.getByIndex(0)
```

I assume `A<T>.get` returns `String`, so the code in `B` makes sense; if it depends on `T`, you still have problems.

Comment: Ah sorry, I saw my code was wrong. Yeah `A.get()` should return `types[i].getData()` or it returns empty String. I think your way will work. I noticed that this seems normal in both Java in Kotlin, I will have to be careful next time. Thanks